# Converting stored, pipe-delimited string back into dates, commas (decimal-delimiter) stripped from it

Tags: vba, excel

In a worksheet I am making, I am storing some old data as pipe-delimited strings.

The function for storing the data is this:

```
target_cell.Offset(0, i) = Join(Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(source_range(i).Resize(, 1)), "|")
```

which works fine, and produces a string looking something like this:

```
42145,5416666662|42145,6249999996|42145,2083333329|42144,8333333329|42145,9999999996
```

Now, on occasion, I want to have a look at my old data, and therefore attempt to write it to a worksheet. The part of my code which does this looks like this:

```
  temp_arr = Split(source_cell.Offset(0, i), "|", -1, vbTextCompare)
  target_range(i).Resize(, 1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(temp_arr)
  For Each c In target_range(i).Resize(, 1)
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
      c = CDate(c)
      c.NumberFormat = "dd. mmm kl. hh"
    End If
  Next
```

However, I get an overflow error on the line `c = CDate(c)`, and when I look at the worksheet the values I find are `421455416666662`, `421456249999996`, etc., in other words it looks like the commas have been stripped from the values somewhere along the way of writing them back to the worksheet.

Have any of you people got any idea of what step in the process removes the commas, and what I can do to avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is getting stripped because Excel may be erroneously assuming it is a **thousands separator**.

**EDIT#1**

Using your data, I ran:

```
Sub ytrewq()
   Dim s As String, D As Date
   s = "42145,5416666662"
   s = Replace(s, ",", ".")
   Range("A1").Value = s
   D = CDate(Range("A1").Value)
   MsgBox D
End Sub
```

and got:

[image]

I just don't know if this will work for your Region.

Comment: Any way to avoid having it stripped? Or should I just reinsert it in the cell 5 characters from the left (I think most dates should be in the 40000's)? Unless someone comes up with another good solution here, I think that may just be what I go for.

Comment: @eirikdaude  **You must experiment**  I can't replicate your issue because of my Regional settings.

Comment: I've been doing a bit of that already ;) Will see what I can figure out though.

Comment: Yep, that (or a slightly modified version of it) actually worked - thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You could handle runtime error 6 / Overflow:

```
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    Dim value As String    

    For Each c In target_range(i).Resize(, 1)
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            value = c.value
            c.Value = CDate(value)
            c.NumberFormat = "dd. mmm kl. hh"
        End If
    Next

CleanExit:
    Exit Sub 'Function?
ErrHandler:
    If Err.Number = 6 Then 'overflow
        value = Left$(value, 5) & "," & Right$(value, Len(value) - 5)
        Resume
    Else
        MsgBox "Unhandled error: " & Err.Description
        Resume CleanExit
    End If
```

This handler assumes the only possible overflow error is because the conversion of `value` to a `Date` overflows for the reason you specified. Might not be ideal. It also assumes regional settings and that the numeric date has 5 digits.. which *should* be the case, unless your data is ***really really*** old.

Comment: Yeah, I think this would work, was almost done inserting it into my module, when I saw Gary's Student's update below, which I prefer because it requires less code in the module - I just replace the commas with periods when I write them to storage.

Comment: Gary's answer solves the problem at the root. This is just a hacky work-around. You accepted the correct answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Change `c = CDate(c)` to `c = CDate(c.Text)`

Comment: Nope. `CDate(c)` is leveraging the *default value* of the range - this would overflow just the same, since `c.Text` is `421455416666662`.

Comment: I am assuming that c.Text would contain the comma?

Comment: Read the OP again ;-)

Comment: @Mat'sMug Actually it changes the error to a type mismatch, probably because the visible text of the cell is `#########`. But yeah, this answer doesn't work even if I increase the width of the column.